# How to aggregate scores

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this cypher query:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("names","John Snow") YIELD node, score
WITH node, score MATCH (node)-[c:ACTIVE]->() WHERE c.is_active = 'True'
RETURN DISTINCT node, score ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
```

I would like to filter results based on score percentile, so probably I need `percentileDisc() as pd` aggregation and then `WHERE score > pd` clause. How do I apply it here? `percentileDisc(score, 0.5)` always gives score itself.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("names","John Snow") YIELD node, score
WHERE EXISTS ((node)-[:ACTIVE {is_active: 'True'}]->())
WITH COLLECT({node: node, score: score}) AS data, percentileDisc(score, 0.5) AS p
UNWIND data AS d
WITH p, d
WHERE d.score > p
RETURN p, d.node AS node, d.score AS score
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
```